# Error when adding custom taxonomy to wp nav menu

Tags: custom-taxonomy, navigation

I have the plugin CustomPress from wpmudev. I know longer have my membership there as it was just to pricey. I am also using there theme wpmu_dixi with some of my own customizations and tweaks. None of those tweaks where to its cor files i just added some new widget locations and messed with the css.

Anyways when i go to add a menu item from the custom taxonomy (ie action) which is under the taxonomy type Movies it spits out the following error in the custom menu area (wp-admin/nav-menus.php)

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string
path-to-site/entertain/wp-admin/includes/nav-menu.php on line 73
```

*i removed out my path

I am using wordpress in network mode and have tried creating a tag that was far off and still nothing. The tag action appears on another sub-site but since i tried using a random tag this should not be the problem. I have searched on a few articles and the closest i could find is this one http://premium.wpmudev.org/forums/topic/custompress-error-adding-custom-post-type-via-taxonomies-to-menu

Comment: I also just wanted to mention the the capability type is set to page

Comment: OK so i have figured out that it has something to do with the custompress plugin itself as i tried it on another subsite with the default twentyten theme and no other plugins enabled network wide and site and still no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that it is the plugin i am using and have instead decided to use the register function